# Creating a button in google sheets to transfer a cell value to the cell next to it

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am managing a sheet to track delivery schedules.
The sheet contains two dates for each delivery entry: 1) this week's delivery date, and 2) the next delivery date

When delivery is complete, I want "the next delivery date" to replace the date that is in "this week's delivery date", thereby updating the delivery schedules.

For example, if column A is "this week's delivery date" and column B is "next upcoming delivery date", I want to move the date in column B to column A upon clicking a button.

Also, I am having difficulties with adding a certain number of days to the date in a cell. 
I tried to use the function belo to add 7 days to the date with failed delivery, but it seems adding the number 7 in apps script does not mean adding 7 days in the corresponding cell.

I used this:

```
function transferfail(){

  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("J4");
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  cell.setNumberFormat("yyyy. M. d").setValue(cellValue + 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to copy selected cell to column A cell.

> I want to move the date in column B to column A upon clicking a button.

Here is the script, all you have to do is select the cell and run it,

```
function copyToColumnA() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // selected cell in column B
  let selected = ss.getSelection().getCurrentCell();

  // copy value from selected cell and paste it to column A
  ss.getRange(selected.getRow(), 1).setValue(selected.getValue())

}
```

for example click on B4 and Run the script

[image]

### Result

[image]

### Reference

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)
- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow())